# Concatenate ints inside array golang - GoLang

Tags: arrays, go, int, slice

I have an array with 3 positions, imagine it has the number 5 in all of them.

```
[5 5 5]
```

how can I pass it to a var in a way that it stays 555? just like this.

```
n:= 555
```

Comment: If the array has always 3 positions you can use the fmt.Sprintf("%d%d%d", array[0], array[1], array[2])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way you would in any other language:

```
s := []int{1, 2, 3}
n := 0
for _, sn := range s {
    n *= 10
    n += sn
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/SSemwbJuTz.

**Edit:** if you're planning to work with more that just single-digit numbers, the loop is a bit trickier:

```
for _, sn := range s {
    shift := 10
    for shift < sn {
        shift *= 10
    }
    n *= shift
    n += sn
}
```

This works with inputs like `[]int{1, 23, 456}`: http://play.golang.org/p/h1xsu9vtmP.

Look out for the [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) though.

Comment: Well, OP asked for an array, not a slice ;-) And your solution fails for integers >= 10 ;-)

Comment: @Volker my initial version *does* work with arrays since `for range` doesn't care. As for `sn >= 10` case, see edit :P

Comment: @Ainar-G I was joking. Your solution was perfectly fine (But the question was pretty strange.)

Comment: @Volker I know it was a joke. I just played along :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have result as string

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    a := []int{1, 2, 3,4}
    s := ""
    for _, c := range a {
        s += strconv.Itoa(c)
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: It'd be much wiser to first work with bytes and only convert to `string` at the end. Otherwise you may generate a lot of garbage strings in the process.